# Connecting Elasticsearch from DBeaver

Tags: elasticsearch, dbeaver

I am trying to connect Elasticsearch database from DBeaver which is SSL secured.

While connecting I get below error. Not sure how to connect to Elasticsearch from DBeaver

```
Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to the database
  Cannot POST address https://XXXXXX:9200/?error_trace (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
  Cannot POST address https://XXXXXX:9200/?error_trace (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```